# Modify rows between two flags (values) in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe with the same shape based on two existing dataframes. I have one dataframe that represents the flags and another one with the values I want to replace.

The `flag` dataframe has only **1, -1 and NaNs**, and always after a 1 I'll have a -1. So basically its a "changing state" kind of dataframe. What I want to do is: in between the interval of 1 and -1, I need to fill in the average of the same interval in the second dataframe, `PR`.

```
flag = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'col2': [np.nan,1,-1,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,-1],
                   'col3': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,-1],
                   'col4': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,-1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
                   })

PR = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [81,81.3,80.7,81.5,81,80.4,80.3,81,79.5,80.7],
                   'col2': [80.9,81.6,81.2,81.7,80.9,79.7,79.3,79.1,79,77.5],
                   'col3': [81.1,81.3,81,81.6,80.8,79.5,79.2,78.8,78.8,77.4],
                   'col4': [80.1,80.6,79.9,80.4,80.4,79.3,79,78.8,78.4,77]
                   })
```

This would have to give me:

```
   col1   col2   col3   col4
0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   NaN  81.40    NaN    NaN
2   NaN  81.40    NaN    NaN
3   NaN    NaN  79.44    NaN
4   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
5   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
6   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
7   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
8   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
9   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a custom function:

```
def process(s, ref=flag):
    f = ref[s.name] # get matching flag

    # create group and mask data outside of 1 -> -1
    m = (f.map({1: True, -1: False}).ffill()
         | f.eq(-1)
        )
    group = f.eq(1).cumsum().where(m)

    # transform to mean
    return s.groupby(group).transform('mean') 

out = PR.apply(process, ref=flag).round(2)
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2   col3   col4
0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   NaN  81.40    NaN    NaN
2   NaN  81.40    NaN    NaN
3   NaN    NaN  79.44    NaN
4   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
5   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
6   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
7   NaN  79.25  79.44  79.03
8   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
9   NaN  79.25  79.44    NaN
```

Comment: When using in my original dataframe, I noticied that for some intervals that are NaN, in between **-1 and 1** (that should be NaN indeed) is returning the average from PR. Do you know how can I correct this?

Comment: @Pedro I see what's going on. I need to change the mask. I'll do that a bit later, AFK now.

Comment: See update (I didn't test with your data)

Comment: The updated version gives all NaN unfortunately. Please see this image that ilustrates what's happening: [example](https://ibb.co/gPtbz6s). The read intervals (after the -1) should all be NaN's

Comment: @Pedro there was a typo (I had updated from my phone yesterday without a possibility to check), it should have been `f`, not `s`.

Comment: I updated your example to demonstrate a case with an internal gap

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much once again for your attention!